# Deleted a file out side Visual Studio, TFS doesn't recognize it

Tags: tfs

I am new to TFS. I checked out a folder from TFS using Visual Studio and then deleted bunch of files/added couple of files within that folder using windows explorer (actually I didn't do it, but that folder has third party libraries and I used an installer which made all these changes).

Now if I go to Visual Studio and try to check in that folder, I am getting this error:

> Check in:  Operation not performed
>
> Could not find file : /ThirdPartyFolder/aDeletedFile.aspx

I tried to follow the solution proposed in this post, but that didn't work out:
http://www.woodwardweb.com/tfs_top_tip/tfs_top_tip_11.html

When I do 'Get Specific Version' and specified 'change set 1', it doesn't show the deleted files in red as it does in the screenshot of that blog post. Also, when I click OK, it shows the Pending Changes-Conflicts window with all the files that got deleted. Even though I selected "Keep Local Version", when I try to check in, I am getting the same error again.

Is there a way in TFS to take what is in my local version and over write what is in the server with my local version files?

I have done similar operations using Subversion, and this has never been a problem. Hopefully someone will let me know how to achieve this in TFS.

Answer (score 11):

Team Foundation Server requires that you explicitly pend changes for these files - if you delete a file locally, this does not explicitly pend a delete against Team Foundation Server.  This is actually a useful feature - the server optimizes the data it sends you based on its knowledge of your local filesystem.  That is to say, if you say "get latest", it knows your current versions and will only deliver the changes.  If you're working with very large projects, this can be very efficient.

However, when other programs decide to make changes without pending the changes to the server, things can get a bit confused.  Fortunately, TFS has the ability to detect changes that were made outside without explicitly pending those changes.  You can use the "return online" capabilities of your TFS client.

You'll need the [Team Foundation Server Power Tools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/bb980963) installed, then you can simply run:  `tfpt online` to detect those changes and select which ones to pend to the server.

Comment: The next TFS version (v11) changes this: https://blogs.msdn.com/b/bharry/archive/2011/08/02/version-control-model-enhancements-in-tfs-11.aspx

Comment: Thanks Edward! I am installing TFS Power tools now, and hopefully get this resolved. Will post back about my experience soon.

Comment: @Lars, that was a very useful link. It is great to know that these changes are coming

Comment: I have files deleted from the file system and I am getting the same error. I installed power tools and ran tfpt online, and it did not work... any other options? If only I could convince my company to move to distributed vcs... then all would be happy in the world.

Comment: You ran `tfpt online /deletes` in the root folder?  (`tfpt online` does not scan for deletions by default, it requires that command-line argument.)

Comment: @LarsTruijens The feature you referred to ([local workspaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/vstudio/bb892960.aspx)) has indeed made it into TFS 2012 and is the default (but projects migrated over from TFS 2012 or 2008 won't change).

Comment: How is this a "feature"? TFS should be able to recognize local changes and give you the ability to resolve conflicts for them.  I renamed a project and fixed the path by editing the solution file in notepad and renaming the folders, but now TFS has pending check-ins for the old path and has no apparent way for me to tell it to use the new path?  Subversion was much easier.  I've been a Subversion user for years and was afraid of MS screwing up version control.  It seems that at least some of my fears were justified.

Comment: It looks like I spoke a little too soon.  There is a 'Detected Changes' button.  I overlooked it initially.

Comment: @DanCsharpster : if you're looking for a more subversion-like experience, you can put TFS into edit/merge/commit mode by using a "Local Workspace".

Comment: <sigh> Still speaking too soon here.  It seems that the detection feature found the files at the new path, but failed to remove the ones at the old path.  I had to click on 'Go to All Changes', sort by path and click to exclude all the files at the old path.

Answer (score 10):

(VS2012) Select the missing files from TFS "Check In" list and then right click on them and click on "Undo Changes" to exclude them from the list of "Check In"s forever.

Answer (score 1):

This is one of the major differences between svn and tfs. Svn is somehow more integrated with windows shell and every change in your working folder will affect the server on commit. I propose you to perform any *move*, *delete* and *rename* actions within tfs UI, not from shell.

Comment: It's not actually more integrated - svn does a scan of your local filesystem before every commit.  You can emulate the same behavior with TFS by using the online command which, similarly, scans the filesystem.

Comment: But TFS still doesn't things like right-click context menus in windows explorer like TortoiseSVN does, right?  Or does that exist somewhere? I would have figured that would come with the VS installation. That was what I was eluding to and I believe what hsalimi was talking about.  The TortoiseSVN UI is also more up front about showing you nonversioned files or deleted files and will sucessfully commit what it can.  So it seems to me that from a workflow and UI perspective, TFS still has some maturing to do.